# Adding .c files to xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I'm trying to add the hypen library to my Xcode iOS project and it has 4 files: hyphen.c, hyphen.h, hnjalloc.c, hnjalloc.h. I dragged them to my project and hit build, but I'm getting undefined symbols for architecture i386 errors. Am I supposed to take any other steps besides dragging them to my project?

Comment: Rename .c files to .m and check.

Comment: @SIGSEGV When or why would that ever work?

Comment: I think you need to use add file to ,not drag.
and also need to check the real path of your project have files which you added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you've added them to the build target - including a file into the project without including in the build target can easily cause this error.

Comment: You are assuming that @mohabitar is building and running for the simulator (which is likely).   If that is correct, your answer is dead-on.  If not, then there is something else amiss.

Comment: How do I add them to the build target?

Comment: In Xcode 4, you add it in the file inspector (open the file and press ⌘⌥1 if not already visible)

Answer (score 1):

right click on the Source folder (top left where all the folder are) and check add. Then choose the files you wish to add. I tried drag&drop had problems with linker.